# How do you override a stylesheet in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

I am using react-native-scrollable-tab from https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/blob/master/DefaultTabBar.js#L75 and I want to override the 'borderBottomColor' property of 'tabs' from what's provided, '#ccc', to 'white'.

How can I go about doing so in React Native?

For example, I tried the following but did not work:

```
<ScrollableTabView
  style={{borderBottomColor: 'white'}}
>...</ScrollableTabView>
```

EDIT **

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>this.props.tabStyle gives you the ability to override styles.tabs.

What you need to do is:</strike>

```
<ScrollableTabView
   tabStyle={{borderBottomColor: 'white'}}
>...</ScrollableTabView>
```

Ok, so I looked again at the entire code, and it seems that it's not possible to only override this color. The DefaultTabBar gets its override style from the ScrollableTabView parent, but ScrollableTabView doesn't let us pass our own style.
You have two options:

1. implement your own TabBar and pass it to ScrollableTabView through the renderTabBar prop (you could take the DefaultTabBar implementation with your changes). You can find an example of a custom TabBar [Here](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view#injecting-a-custom-tab-bar)
2. Send a PR to the developer and help the entire community - highly recommended :)

Comment: Updated the original post with the pic. It is still visible in grey even after tabStyle={{borderBottomColor: 'white}}. Did I miss something? Did you try it out yourself?

Comment: Just checking to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know!

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. Is there happen to be a good TabBar tutorial?

Comment: Why don't you just take the DefaultTabBar in ScrollableTabView and replace the color you want?.

Comment: but doesn't the DefaultTabBar just stay fixed at the bottom? I would like to use around the middle of the page tho

Comment: You can put the TabBar either at the top or bottom, you can't override it. it's in the ScrollableTabView https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/blob/master/index.js#L290-L292

Comment: Sorry should I actually just copy, paste the DefaultTabBar and edit it, and pass that in?